# Confusing with a php variable issue

Tags: php

In the below code, after the `preg_match`, `$videoinfo['video']['rendering']` most definitely equals "Progressive".

So, I am expecting the final echo to output "Rendering: Progressive Scan".

However, it doesn't.  It outputs "Rendering: Progressive"  Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks for your help!

```
if(preg_match("/^Video Field Order\s+:(.*)$/im",$output,$matches)){
    $videoinfo['video']['rendering'] = $matches[1];
    if($videoinfo['video']['rendering'] == "Progressive"){              
        $videoinfo['video']['rendering'] = 'Progressive Scan';                      
    }               
    echo("Rendering: " . $videoinfo['video']['rendering']);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any trailing spaces in that string? Try `trim($matches[1]);`

Comment: That means the condition is not `true`, which means the string is not actually "Progressive". Likely some additional trailing whitespace or so.

Comment: could be extra space before or after 'Progressive'

Comment: Theres a .(dot) also after Progressive ?

Comment: Yes!  There are trailing spaces.  I knew there was a simple answer here somewhere.  Thanks for helping me track that down!!

Answer (score 3):

You do this

```
echo("Rendering: " . $videoinfo['video']['rendering']);
```

and you say that  It outputs "Rendering: Progressive."

That means that `$videoinfo['video']['rendering']` contains the string `Progressive.`.
Mind the dot!

So it has 1 character extra (the dot), and that's why your equals doesn't work.

Comment: Good catch.  There should not have been that dot there.  Sorry for that confusion.  Editing.